# adobe edge animate integration with phonegap

Tags: cordova, adobe, phonegap-build, adobe-edge

What's the proper way to integrate phonegap into an adobe edge animate web app? After creating a webapp with adobe edge animate and sending it to phonegap build I can't get it to run on an android device and I believe that phonegap is not being initialized since I didn't included it in the webapp beforehand. How may I be able to manage to run the app properly with phonegap integrated in it?

Comment: Is your code available? It should just work.

Comment: I had to include phonegap.js library in the html in order to work.

Comment: Fascinating - the JS library PhoneGap uses just provides the hooks into native device stuff. If you aren't using any native stuff then you don't need it.

Comment: I apologise if my question is not clear enough, but what I was trying to ask is how am I able to include phonegap in adobe edge projects? What's the right way to do it? (sorry about my english)

Comment: Err, you don't include it in EA - you include it in your project in general. Maybe I'm being picky - I think you mean - how do you use both. The thing is - it doesn't matter if you use both - it should just work. I'd start w/ a PG project and then add EA in. As I said - it should just work.